# NextAuth gives client fetch error in local development even though i set NEXTAUTH_URL in env

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I set my NEXTAUTH_URL env variable like so:
`NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000/"`, but nextauth complains saying `[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]` however, i tried using edge and it still gives the same error but it doesnt redirect me to error page after login, while chrome redirects me.

Thanks in advance.